# Streaming CSV to parquet in python

Tags: python, csv, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm looking to stream CSV from an input file and write the corresponding rows into a parquet file. A common tool that's used for this is pyarrow, and they have a way to do this in batch using [`open_csv`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.open_csv.html), getting the table and writing the resulting `pyarrow.Table` as a parquet file using [`pyarrow.parquet.write_table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html). *However, this won't work for a large CSV file which can't be stored in memory, even in arrow's binary format*.

`open_csv` gives us a [CSVStreamingReader](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader.html#pyarrow.csv.CSVStreamingReader) which is great, but we have no `ParquetStreamingWriter` which takes chunks of RecordBatches. There is a [RecordBatchFileWriter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.RecordBatchFileWriter.html) which can stream RecordBatches into a binary arrow file, but I'm looking for parquet.

I'm open to using other libraries if there's no functionalities like this in pyarrow.

Comment: I think you are looking for [pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html) which (despite not having "streaming" in the name) supports incremental output.  For a complete example take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555085/how-can-i-chunk-through-a-csv-using-arrow/68563617#68563617 which shows how to open a large CSV file and chunk it into a parquet file.